# Angularjs - radio button show weird action inside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array which has objects, comes from server.

And I have to make list with this array.

I want to set default value to each radio button,

but only the last item has default value.

Please see my code.

```
    <div id="{{product.product_id}}" class="item-box" ng-repeat="product in cartProducts track by $index">
        <div class="radio-box">
            <input type="radio" name="send_num" ng-checked="product.isBasicNum" ng-click="product.isBasicNum=true"> NumType A
            <input type="radio" name="send_num" ng-checked="!product.isBasicNum" ng-click="product.isBasicNum=false"> NumType B
        </div>
        <div class="radio-box">
            <input type="radio" name="send_res" ng-checked="product.isImmediateSend" ng-click="product.isImmediateSend=true"> SendType A
            <input type="radio" name="send_res" ng-checked="!product.isImmediateSend" ng-click="product.isImmediateSend=false"> SendType B
        </div>
        <div class="radio-box">
            <input type="radio" name="receive" ng-checked="product.isRecieveDupable" ng-click="product.isRecieveDupable=true"> ReceiveType A
            <input type="radio" name="receive" ng-checked="!product.isRecieveDupable" ng-click="product.isRecieveDupable=false"> ReceiveType B
        </div>
    </div>
```

and [this is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/hm4x3mya/8/).

What did I miss?

I've tried to find answer, but I could not find similar with mine.

How to set default value to all items?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All radio buttons share the same three `name` attribute values. So you've mistakenly put them into groups. This means when you click one radio (setting it to true) the browser automatically sets all other radios to false that are in the same group.

Clicking on the radios will show you this fact. You need to use different `name` attribute values. Note my use of `{{$index}}` in the below example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope){
 $scope.cartProducts = [
  {product_id:1291803},
  {product_id:2365123},
  {product_id:5463434},
  {product_id:8752642},
  {product_id:4566484}
 ];
 $scope.initDefValue = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.cartProducts, function (product) {
            product.isBasicNum = true;
            product.isImmediateSend = true;
            product.isDirectEnterNum = true;
            product.isRecieveDupable = true;
            product.isBasicBanner = true;
        });
    };
 $scope.initDefValue();
});
```

```css
.item-box {
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
 <div ng-controller="MyController">
  <div id="{{product.product_id}}" class="item-box" ng-repeat="product in cartProducts track by $index">
   <div class="radio-box">
    <input type="radio" name="send_num{{$index}}" ng-checked="product.isBasicNum" ng-click="product.isBasicNum=true"> NumType A
    <input type="radio" name="send_num{{$index}}" ng-checked="!product.isBasicNum" ng-click="product.isBasicNum=false"> NumType B
   </div>
   <div class="radio-box">
    <input type="radio" name="send_res{{$index}}" ng-checked="product.isImmediateSend" ng-click="product.isImmediateSend=true"> SendType A
    <input type="radio" name="send_res{{$index}}" ng-checked="!product.isImmediateSend" ng-click="product.isImmediateSend=false"> SendType B
   </div>
   <div class="radio-box">
    <input type="radio" name="receive{{$index}}" ng-checked="product.isRecieveDupable" ng-click="product.isRecieveDupable=true"> ReceiveType A
    <input type="radio" name="receive{{$index}}" ng-checked="!product.isRecieveDupable" ng-click="product.isRecieveDupable=false"> ReceiveType B
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooooopps! What a silly mistake.. What did I done... Thank you for your answer. I've got suffered from this problem for six hours.. lol

Comment: Oh! Well glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

There should be different `name` attributes for each iteration of the product.

For example, instead of just `send_num`, you can name the radio of the first product to be `send_num_1291803`, `send_num_2365123` for the second product, and so on.

Here is some sample code:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="{{getSendNumName(product)}}" ng-checked="product.isBasicNum" ng-click="product.isBasicNum=true"> NumType A
<input type="radio" name="{{getSendNumName(product)}}" ng-checked="!product.isBasicNum" ng-click="product.isBasicNum=false"> NumType B
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getSendNumName = function(product) {
    return 'send_num_' + product.product_id;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I've just realized this in answer of @RandyCasburn. Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: No need for the extra function call. `ng-repeat` provides an `$index` value for each iteration.

Comment: You're right. I can simplify my code by following your suggestion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your radio button's has the same name when you're performing loop. That's why the last item will be only selected.

Try this code

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope){
 $scope.cartProducts = [
  {product_id:1291803},
  {product_id:2365123},
  {product_id:5463434},
  {product_id:8752642},
  {product_id:4566484}
 ];
 $scope.initDefValue = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.cartProducts, function (product) {
            product.isBasicNum = true;
            product.isImmediateSend = true;
            product.isDirectEnterNum = true;
            product.isRecieveDupable = true;
            product.isBasicBanner = true;
        });
        console.log($scope.cartProducts);
    };
 $scope.initDefValue();
});
```

```css
.item-box {
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="MyApp">
 <div ng-controller="MyController">
  <div id="{{product.product_id}}" class="item-box" ng-repeat="product in cartProducts track by $index">
   <div class="radio-box">
    <input type="radio" name="send_num-{{$index}}" ng-checked="product.isBasicNum" ng-click="product.isBasicNum=true"> NumType A
    <input type="radio" name="send_num-{{$index}}" ng-checked="!product.isBasicNum" ng-click="product.isBasicNum=false"> NumType B
   </div>
   <div class="radio-box">
    <input type="radio" name="send_res-{{$index}}" ng-checked="product.isImmediateSend" ng-click="product.isImmediateSend=true"> SendType A
    <input type="radio" name="send_res-{{$index}}" ng-checked="!product.isImmediateSend" ng-click="product.isImmediateSend=false"> SendType B
   </div>
   <div class="radio-box">
    <input type="radio" name="receive-{{$index}}" ng-checked="product.isRecieveDupable" ng-click="product.isRecieveDupable=true"> ReceiveType A
    <input type="radio" name="receive-{{$index}}" ng-checked="!product.isRecieveDupable" ng-click="product.isRecieveDupable=false"> ReceiveType B
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're also right. I could realize this through @RandyCasburn. It was just my foolish mistake. Thank you for your answer :)